# Disparity in Facebook Graph API profile picture size between Chrome and Firefox/Safari

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api

I currently have the following code to pull the profile picture of the current user from the Facebook Graph API in my Rails app:

```
<%= image_tag "http://graph.facebook.com/#{@user.uid}/picture?width=100&height=100" %>
```

In Chrome, this produces an image of width and height 100px, as expected, but in Firefox and Safari this is 200px by 200px, why is this?

Comment: I'm not into ruby to be honest buy you tagged `CSS`, you can trying inspecting the element to what actual height & width does it have

Comment: The values above are what I got when I inspected them in Firefox/Chrome. I was developing in Firefox most of the time, and was wondering why if I wanted it at 200x200, I had to set it to 100x100. Then I tested it in Chrome and see it's actually 100x100. Bizarre.

Comment: If I enlarge the Chrome img to 200x200 via CSS, it becomes clear it is not a native 200x200 img like the one pulled from the Graph API for Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Even more bizarre, refreshed the page in Chrome again, now it's 200x200 like Safari and Firefox! Guess I'll put this one down to a temporary issue?

Comment: I tried the sending the same `width` & `height` on jsFiddle the img size returned the same in both Chrome & Firefox

Comment: Yeah, it just seemed to start working ago 10 mins ago despite not working the past few hours, don't know what it was <shrugs>

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working normally now despite not making any changes to the code and testing multiple times a few hours ago. Don't know what the issue was...